# Python do _GET request doesn't get completed BaseHTTPRequestHandler for Oracle startup command

Tags: python, oracle

As a part of devops I am building a tool to start/stop a database hosted on the same server as an application.

From the UI, I am making a GET request to start and stop the server.

Once the request comes, I execute a command using the Python `subprocess` module.

I am able to stop and start successfully. However, in the 'start' case the Python request doesn't get completed and a response never returns to the browser. The same case happens by hitting GET request from browser; it continues to show a loading icon on the browser tab even though a response is displayed.

Here is my code for start and stop:

Two multiple lines variable:

```
shutdown_cmd="""
    sqlplus '/ as sysdba' <<!
    shutdown immediate;
    !
    """



startup_cmd="""
    sqlplus '/ as sysdba' <<!
    startup;
    exit;
    !
    """
```

The code to execute the above commands using `subprocess` in Python:

```
call(shutdown_cmd, shell = True)

call(startup_cmd, shell = True)
```

In the case of a shutdown command, the following code gets executed and requests get completed as follows:

```
SQL> Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> 
SQL> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
<machine_name>- - [10/Jan/2017 07:15:45] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

In case of startup command code gets executed and requests gets completed as follows:

```
SQL> ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  275615744 bytes
Fixed Size                  2252384 bytes
Variable Size             218104224 bytes
Database Buffers           50331648 bytes
Redo Buffers                4927488 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
```

The difference I see for shutdown is some `favicon.ico` request is triggered when completion is requested. For startup it gets stuck on the last line and no `favicon.ico request` is triggered.

*

> To summarize, When browser makes GET request to python hosted HTTP
>   server, in case of shutdown command of oracle response is returned,
>   however in case of startup command of oracle response doesnt return
>   though command was execute and database was started, and server
>   continues to wait for response.

*

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I tried editing your post to improve clarity, but your English is hard to understand. Can you check to make sure I haven't inadvertently altered what you're trying to say?

Comment: have added summary, can you help